# How to display a text in one format without actually saving it

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I want to display text in one format to the user without actually saving it.

```
string area = TextField.Text.Substring(0, 6);
                string major = TextField.Text.Substring(6, 4);
                string minor = TextField.Text.Substring(10, 4);
                CardNumberTextField.Text = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", area, major, minor);
```

This works fine where it displays as expected but now `TextField.Text` also stores the value in same format, is there a better way where it just displays the text in one way but stores in normal format without spaces.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking but the displayed text will be what is in the `Text` property. You could have the none formatted text in the `Tag` property...

Comment: I meant if the user enter 10 dights(1234567890) for say, phone number I want the textfield.text to save as 1234567890 but should display 123-456-7890.

Comment: I think what you need is a masked text box, perhaps like the one you find in the Extended WPF Toolkit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest answer would be to leave everything exactly the way it is, but before you store the phone number strip any non-numeric characters.  This is assuming that when you say the word `store` you mean persisting to some database/file.

A quick way to do that would be to:

```
private static string RemoveNonNumeric(string input)
{
    return new string(input.Where(x => char.IsDigit(x)).ToArray());
}
```

If you just mean that you want the `Text` property of the TextField to be correct than I will have to ask a couple questions:

1. You have tagged MVC but it looks like you are using WebForms controls, is there a requirement for that or can you utilize HTML/JS and Razor for this?
2. If WebForms is hard requirement, have you tried using a WebForms HiddenField?  You could keep the TextField as a display to the user, but use JS to sync the HiddenField to the Textfield (removing all non-numeric).  Then bind your HiddenField to whatever you need to on the server.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the answer you are looking for but perhaps this will get you started in the right direction. You could try using string format in this manner.

```
CardNumberTextField.Text = string.Format("{0:###-###-####} {1} {2}", area, major, minor);
```

Comment: Well i tried it but with this format, `CardNumberTextField.Text` would also have the text in the same format, i want plain number in the `CardNumberTextField.Text` and just display to user in "{0:###-###-####}"  format